# PIL.Image.verify() breaks ability to convert PIL image to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

This code works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image


img = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
img_np = np.array(img)
print(img_np.dtype, img_np.shape)

> uint8 (192, 256)
```

When I add `verify()`, `img_np` becomes an object, not the image data:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image


img = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
img.verify()
img_np = np.array(img)
print(img_np.dtype, img_np.shape)

> object ()
```

Is there a way to convert the PIL image to numpy after `verify()`? Or do we really have to open the image again? The following does work, but is hacky.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image


img = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
img.verify()
img = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
img_np = np.array(img)
print(img_np.dtype, img_np.shape)

> uint8 (192, 256)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify):

> `Image.verify()`
>
> Verifies the contents of a file. For data read from a file, this method attempts to determine if the file is broken, without actually decoding the image data. If this method finds any problems, it raises suitable exceptions. **If you need to load the image after using this method, you must reopen the image file.**